# Hibernate Envers not Finding JPA Transaction:

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions, hibernate-envers

I've been trying to wrap my head around this issue all day.

Currently our project has setup JPATransactionManager through a Spring Application Context to take care of our various session transactions with the use of @Transactional on all services that take care of persistence and deletions (DAO usage).

Changing over from Hibernate 3 to 5, we wanted to remove our use of a custom audit interceptor and move onto using Hibernate Envers. I have annotated all my classes properly and have the tables being created, but once it actually gets to a point of insertion, the listener throws an error in which it can't find the current transaction given by JPA:

```
org.hibernate.envers.exception.AuditException: Unable to create revision because of non-active transaction
    at org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.BaseEnversEventListener.checkIfTransactionInProgress(BaseEnversEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl.onPostInsert(EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.postInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:651)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:643)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:638)
```

Looking inside the code, it seems that it's basing the transaction status off it's default value of INACTIVE meaning that it's not hooking into the transaction properly. I know that Hibernate Envers also automatically pushes the listeners into hibernate with recent versions so I don't know if this may also be a source of the issue.

I know that its been documented to work with HibernateTransactionManager but we wish to step away from using that in favor of hooking up our transactions and sessions solely via Spring making things easier so it may also be the need of finding an alternative to envers. Does anyone have any advice or solutions to this problem? Or also hit this issue?

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref=“dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://.." />
    <property name="username" value=“..." />
    <property name="password" value=“..." />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <ref bean="hibernateProperties" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txProxyTemplate" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="find*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,readOnly
            </prop>
            <prop key="load*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,readOnly
            </prop>
            <prop key="make*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="add*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="refresh">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS</prop>
            <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,readOnly
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>
```

**hibernate.properties**

```
#hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.show_sql=true

hibernate.connection.datasource=java\:comp/env/datasource
#hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider

hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
#hibernate.generate_statistics=true
hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries=true
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect

hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister=false
org.hibernate.envers.track_entities_changed_in_revision=false
org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix=AUD_
org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix=
```

My DAOs are hooked up using the txProxyTemplate like so

```
<bean id="objectDAO" parent="txProxyTemplate">
    <property name="target">
        <bean
            class="path.to.objectDAOImpl">
            <property name="sessionFactory">
                <ref local="sessionFactory" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

All my services that use the various DAOs are simply hooked up using the @Transactional annotation where we want to have transactions. I've been able to see through trace that my transactions are succeeding in completing and rolling back as well when there are errors. Once I added envers into the mix, the auditing can't find the transaction to join. There must be something I'm missing but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Can you update your post with your spring configuration for the EntityManagerFactoryBean, TransactionManager, and such?  I have no such problems with Envers in a fully configured spring environment.

Comment: Just expanded the example with my current configuration. Sorry for the late response!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you need to define a `txProxyTemplate` bean nor a `SpringTransactionPolicy` from my experience.  This functionality has since been superseded with the `<tx:/>`  tags and the use of the `@Transactional` annotation.

You just need to make sure a `JpaTransactionManager` has been created and associated as the `transactionManager` associated with the `<tx:annotation-driven/>` tag.